# Как в layout подгрузить данные из базы данных

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

В общем у меня на сайте есть кнопка логин регистр и сё как у людей, я ещё хочу добавить картинку юзеру, чтобы можно было из бд подгружать картинку залогинившемуся пользователю, я даже уже научился менять картинку у юзера, но делаю это я на другой странице, проще говоря, у меня есть кнопка edit Алексей например, если юзера зовут Алексей, нажимая, я захожу на др страницу и там могу поменять картинку и имя пользователя, всё работает отлично в бд изменения сохраняются, но как мне показать эту картинку на первой странице, причем не в index, а в header например (у меня есть отдельное меню) ну суть в общем в том, что это должен быть layout, но у layout нет action и передать туда ничего не получается, может можно как-то через ViewBag? Вообще я могу в ayout обратиться к User.Identity.Name - но здесь я получаю имя, а как получить поле из БД ImagePAth, чтобы отобразить картинку и да я не знаком с AJAX ещё, хотелось бы сделать это статически пока, а потом уже думать о js. База данных у меня SSMS если это понадобится, технология ASP net core

Comment: Если без ajax, то нужно полностью перезагружать страницу. Изучите туториал по MVC, [controller methods and views](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-5.0) - смотрите, как сделаны действия Edit и Create: добавляется или изменяется информация, сохраняется в БД, после чего происходит перенаправление на другую страницу.

Comment: Александр, добрый день. Я более-мение понимаю что как работает, но как загружать картинку в layout не знаю. У меня была мысль при старте приложения в startUp в качестве параметра передавать адрес картинки из БД                 endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); то есть на место id, но у меня не получается это сделать

Comment: Я хотел в класс startUp передать при помощи DI signInManager и ApplicationDbContext, но как я и предполагал этого сделать похоже нельзя, может быть нужно в классе Program выполнять обращение к БД? А затем уже параметром передавать результат в startUp?

Comment: И если я передам параметр в этот id, то это всё-равно будет id в actino Index, а мне нужно чтобы не на Index, а в layout'е у меня оказался путь к картинке, чтобы я мог <img src="здесь путь картинке, в зависимости от авторизованного юзера">, а если не авторизован, то значит картинки не будет вообще

Comment: Сейчас ваши комментарии вижу только я. Отредактируйте вопрос, поместив дополнительную информацию и код в него, тогда он обновится на главной странице сайта и его увидят все. И есть шанс, что кто-нибудь поможет.